# Removing trailing zeros - c++

Tags: c++, trailing

This code:

```
cout<< to_string(x) + "m ----> " + to_string(x *0.001)+ "km"<<endl;
```

with this outputting: 
`0.002000`

However, I want to remove the trailing extra zeros, but it should be in a line of code as i have many lines like the above one.

Comment: Any helpful comments ~ Much appreciated !

Answer (score 1):

Try using `std::setprecsion()`

**Set decimal precision**

Sets the decimal precision to be used to format floating-point values on output operations.

So in your case, you can use :

```
std::cout << std::setprecision(3)
```

This will remove the trailing zeroes from 0.0020000 to 0.002

**Edit**

The below code works when you want to use to_string in your code :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
      int x=1;
      string str2 = to_string(x *0.001);
      str2.erase ( str2.find_last_not_of('0') + 1, std::string::npos );;
      std::cout<<to_string(x)+ "m ----> " + str2+  "km";
}
```

Comment: This isn't related to the problem. The zeros are coming from `to_string`, not `std::cout`.

Comment: cout<<to_string(x) + "m ----> " + to_string(x *0.001)+ "km"<<endl;
How to implement that in this code? i tried 2 ways, didnt worked.

Comment: @3.00AMCoder It seems like you don't need to use `to_string` at all in your code. As explained in the duplicate question, you can't prevent `to_string` from adding trailing zeros. If you do `cout << x << "m ----> " << x * 0.001 << "km" << endl` though you can control the formatting with things like `setprecision`.

Comment: @BessieTheCow yepppp thank you, works prefectly!

Comment: Well, to edit my answer, they below code works : #include <iostream> using namespace std; int main(){ int x=1; std::string str1 = std::to_string (x); string str2 = to_string(x *0.001); str1.erase ( str1.find_last_not_of('0') + 1, std::string::npos ); str2.erase ( str2.find_last_not_of('0') + 1, std::string::npos ); std::cout<<str1 + "m ----> " + str2+ "km"; }

Comment: @3.00AMCoder: please consider, the solution is only works if you want to keep  *three* digit after period. In case your other number doesn't looks like that, it won't work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

try this snipet:

```
cout << "test zeros" << endl;
double x = 200;

cout << "before" << endl;
cout<< std::to_string(x) + "m ----> " + std::to_string(x *0.001)+ "km"<<endl;    


std::string str = std::to_string(x * 0.001);
str.erase ( str.find_last_not_of('0') + 1, std::string::npos );

cout << "after" << endl;
cout<< std::to_string(x) + "m ----> " + str + "km"<<endl;
```

with output:

```
test zeros
before
200.000000m ----> 0.200000km
after
200.000000m ----> 0.2km
```

it is better then `std::setprecision` cause you don't need to decide how many num after period you want to keep, but let the implementation find it for you.

Here the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_last_not_of/) for some extra information.